# Given a sequence of all $\mathbb{Q}$ in [0,1], the Density Theorem implies every number in [0,1] is a subsequential limit

Tags: real-analysis

My textbook reads,

The set of rationals is denumerable, thus it can be written as a sequence $(r_n)$. Then it follows from the Density Theorem that every number in $[0,1]$ is a subsequential limit of $(r_n)$. Thus we have the set $S$ of all subsequential limits as $S=[0,1]$

I don't understand why Density Theorem implies this. Is it because the Density Theorem says that for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, $x<y$ implies there exists $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r<y$ and we can somehow reapply the theorem to show that there isn't just one $r$ between $x$ and $y$ but infinitely many? That would mean with infinite rationals in between two real numbers we can define subsequences with limits to any real number in $[0,1]$.

Comment: That's the basic idea. Take any $x \in [0,1]$. Let $n_1$ be the smallest $n$ such that $|x-r_n| < 1$. Then let $n_2$ be the smallest $n$ greater than $n_1$ such that $|x - r_n| < 1/2$. Continuing like this, we get a sequence $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \cdots$ such that $|x - r_{n_k}| < 1/k$, hence the sequence $r_{n_k}$ converges to $x$. Note that at each step, when we choose $r_{n_k}$, we are exploiting the fact that there are infinitely many rationals in the interval $(x - 1/k, x + 1/k)$, i.e. if we go out far enough in the sequence $r_n$, we're guaranteed to find one in that interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less you have the right idea. The better way, in my opinion, to see this is to take $x\in [0,1]$. Then for every $n\in \mathbb{N} $ there exists some rational $q_n $ such that $x-\frac{1}{n}<q_n <x+\frac{1}{n} $. Then $q_n $ converges to $x $.

Comment: I edited $r_n$ into $q_n $ to avoid confusion with the sequence $(r_n)_n$ of the Q, so that the following point will be clear: We are given that  $ \{r_n:n\in \Bbb N\}=\Bbb Q\cap [0,1].$  We are required to find a strictly increasing $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ such that $x=\lim_:n\to \infty}r_{f(n)}. $ Now what happens in your A if $x= r_1 $ and $x\ne r_n$ for $n>1$ and $q_n=x$ for every $n$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks, I appriciate it.